# SQL - How to transform a table with a range of values into another with all the numbers in that range?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a Table (A) with some intervals from *start_val* to *end_val* with an *attribute* for that range of values.

I want a Table (B) in which each row is a number in the interval of *start_val* to *end_val* with the attribute of that range.

I need to do that using SQL.

**Exemple**

**Table A**:

```
+---------+--------+----------+
|start_val| end_val| attribute|
+---------+--------+----------+
| 10      |  12    |  1       |
| 20      |  23    |  2       |
+---------+--------+----------+
```

**Table B** (Expected result):

```
+---------+----------+
|start_val| attribute|
|end_val  |          |
| interv  |          |
+---------+----------+
| 10      |  1       |
| 11      |  1       |
| 12      |  1       | 
| 20      |  2       |
| 21      |  2       |
| 22      |  2       |
| 23      |  2       |
+---------+----------+
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Postgresql?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to do this

```
select m.start_val + n -1 as start_val_computed
      ,m.attribute
 from t m
 join lateral generate_series(1,(m.end_val-m.start_val)+1) n
   on 1=1

+--------------------+-----------+
| start_val_computed | attribute |
+--------------------+-----------+
|                 10 |         1 |
|                 11 |         1 |
|                 12 |         1 |
|                 20 |         2 |
|                 21 |         2 |
|                 22 |         2 |
|                 23 |         2 |
+--------------------+-----------+
```

working example

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=ce9e13765b5a4c3616d95ec659c1dfc9

Comment: Note that you can use `cross join` and remove the `on` clause.

Comment: thanks @GordonLinoff that was a new learning for me today. I also tried a regular join, without the "on" clause and found that it also works.

Answer (score 1):

You may use a calendar table approach:

```
SELECT
    t1.val,
    t2.attribute
FROM generate_series(10, 23) AS t1(val)
INNER JOIN TableA t2
    ON t1.val BETWEEN t2.start_val AND t2.end_val
ORDER BY
    t2.attribute,
    t1.val;
```

Note: You may expand the bounds in the above call to `generate_series` to cover whatever range you think your data would need.

Comment: What if new data is inserted to a table. In that case your query should be updated. I think you should write ```start_val``` and ```end_val``` inside ```generate_series``` instead of static values.

Comment: I have already given a caveat and suggestion regarding your point.

Answer (score 1):

This is a variant of George's solution, but it is a bit simpler:

```
select n, m.attribute
from t m cross join lateral
     generate_series(m.start_val, m.end_val) n;
```

The changes are:

- `CROSS JOIN` instead of `JOIN`.  So, no need for an `ON` clause.
- No arithmetic in the `GENERATE_SERIES()`.
- No arithmetic in the `SELECT`.
- You can just call the result of `GENERATE_SERIES()` whatever name you want in the result set.

Postgres actually allows you to put `GENERATE_SERIES()` in the `SELECT`:

```
select generate_series(m.start_val, m.end_val) as n, m.attribute
from t m;
```

However, I am not a fan of putting row generating functions anywhere other than the `FROM` clause.  I just find it confusing to figure out what the query is doing.